# POST 400 and 404 (Not Fount) errors take place at the same time

Tags: rest

When I upload file in a project, I get an error pop-up saying "invalid input syntax for integer: "2.01e+18".

And then when I check the concole, I get POST 400 and 404 (Not Found) errors.

```
POST https://api-staging.helloshop.com/v1/importer 400

POST http://localhost:3000/bags 404 (Not Found)
```

(I am using express.js by the way)

Is there any possible reason why both errors take place at the same time?.

Answer (score 0):

You are making two requests, one for https://api-staging.helloshop.com/v1/importer, and one for http://localhost:3000/bags, and as result - recieving two errors.

Browser devtools also have a network tab where you can see which requests are you sending.

Comment: So I am sending two post request to https://api-staging.helloshop.com/v1/importer and http://localhost:3000/bags which means a data I sent to api-staging.helloshop does not fit to server's standard and the other request I sent to localhost:3000 does not have response I have?